# Lookup in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is similar to:

```
grades=pd.DataFrame(columns=["person","course_code","grade"],data=[[1,101,2.0],[2,102,1.0],[3,103,3.0],[2,104,4.0],[1,102,5.0],[3,104,2.5],[2,101,1.0]])
```

On each row is the grade of a certain student in certain subject.

And want to convert it to another that looks like this:

```
students=pd.DataFrame(columns=[101,102,103,104],data [[2.0,5.0,"NaN","NaN"],[1.0,1.0,"Nan",4.0],["Nan","Nan",3.0,2.5]])
```

On each row is a student (codex of the row) with the different grades obtained in every subject (every column is a different subject).

I have tried doing this:

```
for subj in grades["COURSE_CODE"].unique():
    grades_subj=grades[grades["COURSE_CODE"]==subj]
    grades_subj = grades_subj.set_index("EXPEDIENT_CODE", drop = True)
    for st in grades["EXPEDIENT_CODE"].unique():
        grade_num=grades_subj.loc[st]["GRADE"]
        student.loc[st][subj]=grade_num
```

But I get:

```
KeyError: 'the label [304208] is not in the [index]'
```

I have tried other ways too and get always errors...

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Which line triggers the error?

Comment: grade_num=grades_subj.loc[st]["GRADE"]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
grades.pivot_table(index='person', columns='course_code', values='grade')
```

The `value` argument let you to choose the aggregation column.

In order to answer your comment below, you can always add different levels when indexing. This is simply done by passing a list rather than a single string to `index`. Note you can do the same in `columns`. SO, based in the example you provide.

```
grades.pivot_table(index=['person','school'], columns='course_code', values ='grade')
```

After this I usually recommend to `reset_index()` unless you are fluent slicing and indexing with `MultiIndex`.

Also, if the correspondence is 1 to 1, you could merge both dataframes using the appropiate join.

Here you have all the information about [Reshaping and Pivot Tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) in Pandas.

Comment: yes that's it. You could add a link to the docs, though.

Comment: @Anderas thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly with the example I gave you, but what if I have other columns that I do not want to pivot? (Student information that I want to keep in the same row and like in the previous dataframe) Should I merge afterwards or is it possible to pivot only certain columns?

Comment: You can choose what column to aggregate when pivoting using the argument `value=`. See my edited answer. If it does not answer your question, please provide a little example of what you want.

Comment: Thanks @GonzaloDonoso.
Imagine my first dataframe was:

    grades=pd.DataFrame(columns=["person","school","course_code","grade"],data=[[1,"a",101,2.0],[2,"b",102,1.0],[3,"c",103,3.0],[2,"b",104,4.0],[1,"a",102,5.0],[3,"c",104,2.5],[2,"b",101,1.0]])

And I want to keep the column school without pivoting, that is:

    students=pd.DataFrame(columns=["school",101,102,103,104],data= [["a",2.0,5.0,"NaN","NaN"],["b",1.0,1.0,"Nan",4.0],["c","Nan","Nan",3.0,2.5]])

Comment: Hello, @MTT. Please, see edited answer. I would also recommend to take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe